# Calculating 7-Day Total on each and every date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL Server database in which the hours worked by each employee by date are stored.  I need to calculate what the total hours worked by each employee in the last 7 days, for each date within my table.

My data looks as follows

[image: Data Table]

And what I want to produce is as follows

[image: Weekly Totals]

Every attempt I have made in T-SQL to build an Query that produces these results will not execute, as I keep wanting to refer to a field from my outer query, in the sub query as follows -

[image: My T-SQL]

I did consider using PARTITION BY but I think that would give me the total of the last 7 entries by Employee rather than the total for the last 7 days (date range), because sometimes there will be no entry for an employee on a certain date (e.g. note there is no entry for Bob on 02/11/2015).

I'm using UK date formats here.

Also the {Start} and {End} are parameters that will be set by the client, so for example, if they wanted to see all the weekly totals in November they would set {Start} = 01/11/2015 and {End} = 30/11/2015.  These will be set in Crystal Reports not in TSQL.  I've just included here to explain what my ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, probably the easiest approach is to use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, tt.weekly
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.daily) as weekly
      from t t2
      where t2.name = t.name and
            t2.date > dateadd(day, -7, t.date) and
            t2.date <= t.date
     ) tt;
```